# how to implement dynamic matching in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to write an if statement in terraform to run the following block with different values according to the environment that will be specified in a variable.

```
root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "30"
  }

  ebs_block_device = {
    device_name = "dfgh"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "5"
    encrypted = true
  }
```

For example, if I want the volume_size argument to be 30 for test environment and 50 for production?

Comment: Where are you defining the environment? Is it a e.g. variable, workspace, git branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use an if statement in Terraform as it is a declarative language.

However there is a workaround to achieve what you are seeking.

```
...

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "${lookup(var.volume_sizes, var.env)}"
  }

...

variable "env" {
  default = "test"
}

variable "volume_sizes" {
  default = {
    "test" = "30"
    "production" = "50"
  }
}
```

You can then change the volume size value by modifying the `env` variable from `test` to `production`.